# How to convince ourself of the presence of Lord?

Tags: belief, practice

This is an era of science in which humans are everything. All the stuff we heard about god is only in the books and there is no proof of god (if there is, then I don't know about it). At a time like this how could we really convince ourself and others that there is god? What is the need of worshipping since it's nowhere written to worship god?

Comment: Krishna said Those who are devotees of other gods and who worship them with faith actually worship only Me, O son of Kuntī, but they do so in a wrong way.  Bhagvat Geeta . 9.23

Comment: Those who worship the demigods will take birth among the demigods; those who worship the ancestors go to the ancestors; those who worship ghosts and spirits will take birth among such beings; and those who worship Me will live with Me  Bhagvat Geeta . 9.25

Comment: Abandon all varieties of Duties and just surrender unto Me(means worship). I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.  BG 18.66

Comment: "And of all yogīs, he who always  abides in Me with great faith, worshiping Me in transcendental loving  service, is most intimately united with Me in yoga and is the highest of all." 
Lord Krishna, Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 6, Verse 47

Comment: worshiping god in Hinduism not compulsory like other religion , Hinduism says do good karma it's means automatically worshiping GOD.

Comment: Good question. However this is a question you need to ask God. If you ask God sincerely 'Oh Loving God, in this age of science, I find it hard to believe in your existence, however I am open to accept all beliefs. Please show me Thy presence'. God does respond to such requests made by His children. He is willing to show His presence to you, provided you remain open to His existence (WARNING: if you are asking God so that you can show off to others, then He may or may not respond :) your seeking should be earnest sir) All the best.

Comment: @Sai isn't like a fairy tale or Santa in home. Actually, what I think is one need to follow brahmacharya, truth at rigrous level for years.   Source :Through continuous pursuit of Satya (truthfulness), Tapas (perseverance, austerity), Samyajñāna (correct knowledge), and Brahmacharya, one attains Atman (Self).

— Mundaka Upanishad, 3.1.5

Answer (score 3):

The question started with the statement

> it is an era of science in which a human is everything .  All the stuff we heard about god is only in the books and there is no proof of god

and ended with the statement

> What is the need of worshipping since its nowhere written to worship the god?

Can we prove to the satisfaction of a questioner, the **Newton's 3rd Law** - For every action, there will be an equal and opposite reaction - only through reading/explaining?

**Not possible, because it can only be experienced.**

---

In my view, no body can provide any authority from any scripture, **for conclusively proving the existence of GOD**, because the concept of GOD is an ABSTRACT thing, **which can only be experienced**, but cannot be proved.

---

Personal experiences/Holy books/Logical arguments are useless to convince anyone that GOD exists.

So let us limit our focus on the issues that are known to every person.

Everybody might have heard the undermentioned words. These are illustrative but not exhaustive.

1. Anger
2. Happiness
3. Jealous
4. Passion
5. Lust
6. Aversion
7. Compassion
8. Forgiveness
9. Indifferent
10. Sympathy
11. Cruelty

Every rational human being with reasonable exposure to the society around him/her might have experienced the above mentioned feelings  at one stage or other of his/her life.

My question is, is it possible to explain:

- For any rational human being experiencing one or combination of two or more feelings mentioned above,  in words or make understand another person, who have no firsthand experience of that feelings, how the feeling look like,  effects his/her personality?
- Why a particular person driven by compassion towards human beings, will leave behind his/her riches/fame/position (like Buddha), works for upliftment of society, living on bare necessities?
- What is the cruelty that provoked Adolf Hitler to butcher thousands of Jews?

It is not possible because it is feeling and an ABSTRACT thing.  And, it is intangible and cannot be explained in words.

The feeling is a force/energy that can either positive or negative.  There are many visible and invisible forces working in this world.

---

The known and unknown negative feelings/forces put together will be known as GOD.  And, it is also an ABSTRACT thing.

It can neither be explained in words nor evidenced by personal experiences of other people.

**It can only be experienced.**

**Neither the believers nor non-believers of GOD** can know the TRUTH. Only a sceptic mind with the intent of knowing the TRUTH will realise the TRUTH.

---

Let us consider one more example:

If somebody wants you to describe the taste of sweet in words, can you do it?

Even if you try to explain the taste of sweet for 1,000 days, the questioner will not understand.  Just put a lump of sugar in his mouth, then he will understand, as taste can only be experienced, as it is intangible.

Similarly, **God is an ABSTRACT thing. Nobody can describe it**. You can only experience it.

Comment: You can actually prove Newton's third law. You see it all the time. You feel it. Most people agree with it. You can record it in a camera. You can record the force with sensors.

Comment: Try using the accelerometer and Gyro in an Android phone. Record the motion using video. Feel the force using your sense of touch. See with your eyes.

Comment: If feelings are abstract then why do chemicals affect the brain. I've used psychological medicine and noticed a lot of my emotions, thoughts etc change.

Comment: Science has proved that chemicals influence thoughts. What part of science contradicts that people can't have different personalities?

Comment: If you believe chemicals don't influence thought then I'd recommend observing alcohol influence.

Comment: @Wally "You can actually prove Newton's third law. You see it all the time. You feel it."... so this is called experience not reading?... Read answer properly...